# Table and column limits in MS Sync Framework

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

Using MS Sync Framework with SqlSyncProvider with SQL Express:  I know sql merge replication places limits on how many columns a table can have, but I haven't seen anything about limits with Sync Framework.  What is the maximum number of tables that can be synchronized and what is the maximum number of columns in a table that can be synchronized with Sync Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik, there is no hard limits. the columns and tables are added in a collection.

having said that, the scope configuration is stored in the scope_config table as an xml column. the scope configuration has a list of all table and columns in a scope and afaik, the xml column has a 2gb limit (i doubt you'll hit a 2gb scope configuration)